# Extracting text from a file and appending the contents at the end of each line in unix

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I want to do as follows in a .txt file.
Contents of file.txt are:

```
w|x|y|z
w1|x1|y1|z1
w2|x2|y2|z2
```

Required result:

```
w|x|y|z|w_x
w1|x1|y1|z1|w1_x1
w2|x2|y2|z2|w2_x2
```

I wish to append the first two pipe seperated words to be appended at the end of each line with a underscore(_) between them in the same file.

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code! StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it. Or if you're starting from somewhere past zero, show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use sed:

```
sed 's/^\([^|]*\)|\([^|]*\).*/&|\1_\2/' file.txt
#         ~~~~~     ~~~~~  ~~ ^   ^ ^
#          1st      2nd  Rest |   | |
#         column  column     All 1st|
#                                   2nd
```

or Perl:

```
perl -plaF'/\|/' -e '$_ .= "|$F[0]_$F[1]"' -- file.txt
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line and prints the output
- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to output
- `-a` split input into the @F array
- `-F` specifies the separator for `-a`

Comment: Would `'s/^\([^|]*\)|\([^|]*\).*/&|\1_\2/'` not be functionally equivalent?

Comment: @ghoti: True, simplified. Thanks. I always forget about `&`.

Answer (score 1):

The "advantage" of perl and (gnu) sed is that they offer an option to overwrite the file with the output, which seems to be the OPs desire.  The disadvantage is that they offer such an option which prevents the user from appreciating that such a thing is not the Unix Way (TM).  Do this with awk, and use the shell to redirect the output as desired (eg, write a temp file and move it if desired).

```
awk '{print $0,$1 "_" $2}' OFS=\|  FS=\| file.txt
```

Comment: Heh, I was thinking more along the lines of `awk -F'|' '{$(NF+1)=$1"_"$2} 1' OFS='|'`

Answer (score 1):

Using purely bash text processing simple commands:

```
cut -d '|' -f 1,2 --output-delimiter='_' t.txt | paste -d '|' t.txt -
```

If your data is in `t.txt` file.

Explanation:

- First part (with `cut`) takes 1st and 2nd column from file and joins them with '_' (output delimiter)
- `paste` joins original file with output from the previous command, line by line, using '|' delimiter (notice `-` mark which is used as standard input taken from piped data from `cut` command)